# How to enable AFM extensions on a Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox 5?

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, cpu

I try to use tensorflow on VirtualBox with Ubuntu 16.04 guest (and windows 7 host), and I get error "tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:36] the TensorFlow library was compiled to use **FMA** instructions, but these aren't available on your machine
CPU model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz

When I check the extensions in the VirtualBox machine, I do not see FMA3/FMA4 listed:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 94
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz
stepping    : 3
cpu MHz     : 4008.008
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca    cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch avx2 rdseed clflushopt
bugs        :
bogomips    : 8016.01
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure your system *supports* FMA extensions?  You might need to use the coreinfo sysinternals tool on the host to confirm it has FMA extension support

Comment: I checked my CPU outside of VirtualBox and it shows the `fma` there.  But when I check it in VirtualBox it does not.  This would be something up to Oracle to add to VirtualBox for support of `fma`.  See https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15471

Comment: @Terrance that sounds like an answer: "You can't, it's not yet supported in VirtualBox"

Answer (score 3):

Even if your CPU supports `FMA` this is not yet supported in VirtualBox.

Please see:  https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15471